# Eclipse jobs not in Spark UI History

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I really like the DAG visualisation on the Spark UI (http://localhost:4040/jobs)

I am running local Spark and when I run a job through Eclipse IDE for Scala, these jobs are not logged in the Spark UI.  Any ideas how i can get these to show?

Comment: While it is running or when it has stopped? When it has stopped and you want to see something, then you should use the spark history server.

Comment: oh, is spark history server something that needs to be set up?

and if i want to view while it is running?

Comment: ok so i now have spark history server running , and it is configured to point  to file:///c:/logs/sparkHistory  on my local machine.  However when i run spark scala through Eclipse, no history is generated.  Any ideas how to configure this?

(fyi, i can see running jobs through localhost:4041)

Comment: can you see your jobs when you run via spark-submit via terminal

Comment: hi there  - looks like i solved the problem below.  Eclipse was not picking up the conf settings from conf\spark-defaults.conf.  So i set these manually within the eclipse scala object

Answer (score 0):

so looks like the Eclipse is not looking at the [SPARK_HOME]\conf\spark-defaults.conf.  There are ideas on how to point to this but none have worked for me.  So I have set the conf properties in the scala code.  Be careful of trailing spaces

```
  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("WordCount")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("spark.history.fs.logDirectory", "file:///c:/tmp/spark-events")
    .set("spark.eventLog.dir", "file:///c:/tmp/spark-events")
    .set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
```

Comment: How do I make eclipse project point to [SPARK_HOME]\conf\spark-defaults.conf instead of setting it in the project?